# How to maintain DatePicKer State After Rotate Screen

Tags: android, datepicker, screen, rotation

I have implemented the Demo version of HelloDatePicker provided by the API.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html

However I cannot maintain its value after rotating the screen. Can someone post an example or indicate how one can do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) to save the date, and in onCreate use [getLastNonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLastNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) to load and set the date.

Comment: What if he needs that for saving a task status??i use the onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState but even with those the date picker will not update correctly in 2.X versions. It does work correctly with ICS version....

Answer (score 0):

Even without a Fragment, the Activity alone can do this:

```
@Override protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState (outState);
    outState.putInt ("YEAR", mDatePicker.getYear ());
    outState.putInt ("MONTH", mDatePicker.getMonth ());
    outState.putInt ("DAY", mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth ());
}

@Override protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState (savedInstanceState);
    mDatePicker.updateDate (savedInstanceState.getInt ("YEAR"),
                            savedInstanceState.getInt ("MONTH"),
                            savedInstanceState.getInt ("DAY"));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After rotation, Activity is recreated. The simplest way to avoid it is to add:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

in AndroidManifest.xml in Activity declaration.

For more information [you should read it](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange).

Comment: If i do you use this and overide onConfigurationChanged() my different layouts vertical-layout and (land-layout) do not work correctly

Comment: Google discourages this approach. Using the Fragment's built-in state-saving/restoring functionality is preferred. Even without a Fragment, the Activity's onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState can do the same.